# Convert large PIL image to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Consider the following script:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.new("F", (512, 512), 0.)
```

This results in

```
>>> np.asarray(im)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

as I expected. However, if I have a larger image, say `im = Image.new("F", (10240, 8600), 0.)`, the conversion results in an array with the PIL image as its only element:

```
>>> np.asarray(im)
array(<PIL.Image.Image image mode=F size=10240x8600 at 0x122D8A08>, dtype=object)
```

Is this behaviour normal? Is there a workaround? Running Python 2.7 and PIL 1.1.7 on a Windows 7 machine. On Unix the problem does not occur.

Comment: Long shot: does `np.asarray(im.getdata())` work better?

Comment: the behavior does not appear on my machine, i'm also using Python 2.7 and PIL 1.1.7 on a Windows 7.

Comment: isnt it just the way your ipython shows your object? I think theres nothing wrong with the resulting object. Maybe put some data in the new object and see if it behaves as it should?

Comment: No, it is not the same. Actually I am accessing the resulting array/matrix at a certain position (i,j). But with the large image (which has the conversion problem) as input this throws an exception stating that the array has size 0 in one dimension. I traced that back to the problematic conversion in the present question.

Comment: There was another question posted recently that had a similar issue except it was the exact same code run on Windows, then linux. On one system, it returned a result as in your first case and on the other it produced your second output. Unfortunately, I can't find the question now.

Comment: What happens when you call `x=list(im)`, does this really give you a list? If so, then you should be able to successfully then execute `np.array(x)`.  Casting the generator to a list is what numpy needs to do first (probably) anyhow.

Comment: Tried to do that, but meanwhile I cannot reconstruct the problem anymore. The conversion works as expected. Should I close the question in this case?

Comment: The problem still exists on google colab